# ASP - Printing the entire request contents

Tags: asp-classic

I'm debugging some ASP code and I need to get a quick printout of the current Request datastructure, which I believe is an array of key/value pairs.

I see that Request.Form("key") is the method for extracting individual elements.

Any tips on printing out the entire thing?

Comment: If you just want a really quick look you can also use Response.Write(Request.Querystring), or Response.Write(Request.Form)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
For Each item In Request.Form
    Response.Write "Key: " & item & " - Value: " & Request.Form(item) & "<BR />"
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

**Working:**

`For x = 1 to Request.Form.Count 
  Response.Write x & ": " _ 
    & Request.Form.Key(x) & "=" & Request.Form.Item(x) & "<BR>" 
Next`

I have other Classic ASP code snippets here:

https://github.com/RaviRamDhali/programming-procedure/tree/master/Snippets/ASP

Answer (score 2):

Try a FOR/EACH loop:

```
for each x in Request.Form
    Response.Write(x)
Next
```