# amp form post action-xhr post data

Tags: asp-classic, http-headers, amp-html

abc.html amp form action-xhr post gonder.asp

gonder.asp > adSoyad = request.form("adSoyad") **not working?**

response.write(adSoyad) **is null?**

**how can I print the incoming data**

screenshot
[enter image description here](https://hizliresim.com/DyavA1)

**General**

```
Request URL:https://www.example.com/gonder.asp?__amp_source_origin=https://www.example.com
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:94.73.170.127:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Respone Headers**

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*.ampproject.org
Amp-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin:https://www.example.com
AMP-Control-Expose-Headers:AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
AMP-Same-Origin:true
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/json; Charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 15 Dec 2017 13:55:43 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk:PleskWin
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
AMP-Same-Origin:true
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:719
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycUwmQDZoBgyFKUhs
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.1081942032.1513186181; _gid=GA1.2.450855249.1513323706; ASPSESSIONIDCWCTASTD=FHBEIINBPGAHAFGEDHNICLDL
Host:www.example.com
Origin:https://www.example.com
Referer:https://www.example.com/abc.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1
```

Query String Paraments

```
__amp_source_origin:https://www.example.com
```

**Request Payload**

**------WebKitFormBoundarycUwmQDZoBgyFKUhs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="adSoyad"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089048/asp-printing-the-entire-request-contents

Comment: looks like your using "multipart/form-data", are you uploading files? if not, remove that enctype from your form, otherwise you'll need to use a 3rd party library to parse out that data

Comment: Need to see the code where you are requesting the asp page.